# Calculating the transparency current of a laser?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, laser

I'm stuck trying to solve analytically the transparency current of a laser, Itr.

I've calculated the transparency carrier density N, and I know the area of the active region A, but simply going Itr=NA gives a value that's unreasonably large.

Are there any other methods to get the transparency current?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the terms you're using, I'll assume you're asking about a current-pumped diode laser.

The key additional information you need is the carrier lifetime due to nonradiative recombination and spontaneous emission events, call it $\tau_R$.

Then the current required to maintain a carrier density of $N$ is

$$I=\frac{qNV}{\tau_R}$$

where $q$ is the elementary charge and $V$ is the volume of the active region.